# Laravel eloquent relationships, 3 way join

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have 3 tables (simplified here)

**users**

id, name, email

**teams**

id, name

**team_user**

team_id, user_id

I want to send an API query to return all teams a user Id belongs to, and what other members are also in that team. Rather than returning just userIds, I want to fill the arrays with their actual user data, e.g name and email.

`Route::get('/user/{id}/teams/', 'UserController@getTeams');`

User.php (model)

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'team_user', 'team_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Team.php (model)

```
class Team extends Model
{    
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'team_user', 'team_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

TeamUser.php (model)

```
class TeamMember extends Model
{    
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Team');
    }
}
```

UserController.php

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getTeams($userId) {

        return User::find($teamId)->teams()->get();
    }
}
```

This returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "P12",
        "location": "Newbury",
        "owner": 6,
        "active": 1,
        "created_at": "2017-12-20 10:18:00",
        "updated_at": "2017-12-20 10:18:00",
        "pivot": {
            "team_id": 6,
            "user_id": 6
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "fwffewfffffff",
        "location": "ffffffff",
        "owner": 4,
        "active": 1,
        "created_at": "2017-12-19 19:56:27",
        "updated_at": "2017-12-19 19:56:27",
        "pivot": {
            "team_id": 6,
            "user_id": 4
        }
    }
]
```

However I would like to also include a list of other users in each of those 2 teams. With their names and emails (from the users table), not just the user_ids.

Is this possible without doing further seperate queries?

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at the [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) Laravel docs. As a start, you should add `team_members` as a second argument to your returns in `User.php` and `Team.php` (and they should both be `belongsToMany`). [This](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/) article may also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be able to eagerly load the relations and attach them to the model.

By using the dot notation `teams.users`, the output will include all users of all teams attached to user with id `$userId`.

I've added the `findOrFail` to make sure it will return a 404 when user can not be found.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getTeams($userId)       
    {
        return User::with('teams.users')->findOrFail($userId);
    }
}
```

This will return the User and attach the relations.

If you want to just return the teams, you can do something like this:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getTeams($userId)       
    {
        $user = User::with('teams.users')->findOrFail($userId);

        // $user->teams will hold a collection of teams with their users
        return $user->teams;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `with()` to retrieve the fields from different tables, for example

```
class UserController extends Controller {
    public function getTeams($userId) {
         return User::find($userId)->with('teams')->get();
         // return User::find($userId)->teams()->get();
    }
}
```

If you would like to select specific column from the **team_members** database, you could add function inside `with`, for example

```
class UserController extends Controller {
    public function getTeams($userId) {
         return User::find($userId)->with(['teams' => function($query) {
             $query->select('id', 'name');
         }])->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no data for users exists in team_members, only the list of user_ids and team_ids. The user names belong in the users table

Comment: updated original question now I have data being returned

Comment: you can obtain the user_team_id and use it to query for Teams Table, `return Teams::where('id', $user_team_id)->with('users')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

For now I have solved this with

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getTeams($userId) {

        $teamWithMembers = [];

        $teams = User::find($userId)->teams()->get();

        foreach($teams as $team) {
            $team->members = Team::find($team->id)->users()->get();
            $teamWithMembers[] = $team;
        }

        return $teamWithMembers;
    }
}
```